# Can I move and rotate objects smoothly with the cursor in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After making an object follow the cursor on the screen and make the camera tilt according to the cursor left-right

***(the way I control the object)*** (*I can't put a picture... So I put it as a link*)
[Pictures of the objects in the event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcrDx.png)

`***Player***` = Game forward object

`Animation Camera` = The object used for rotation, moves from the parent position. and use it as a camera animation

`Main Camera` = Ah yes, it's a camera

now this is my code **But here, in order to make it easier to read So I excluded the irrelevant part**

***This code I added to `***Player***`***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed;
    public float SetSpeed = 10.00f;


    public bool game = false;
    public bool CentrifugalForce = true;

    public string GameMode = "Pxy";

    Vector3 PointOfPlayer = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    Vector3 PlayerPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    Vector2 PointOfMouseOnGame = new Vector3(0, 0);
    Vector2 Move;
    Vector2 Mouse;
    Vector2 ScreenSet;

    void Start()
    {
        ScreenSet = new Vector2(Screen.width / 2,
                                Screen.height / 2);
        PlayerPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (game == true)
        {
            
            Mouse = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x,
                                Input.mousePosition.y);

            Move = new Vector2(Mouse.x - ScreenSet.x,
                               Mouse.y - ScreenSet.y);

            PointOfPlayer = transform.position; //current position----------
            PointOfMouseOnGame = new Vector2(Move.x, Move.y);
            speed = SetSpeed;
            movement = Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
            PlayerPosition += movement * speed; //Player's position in the next frame----------


            if (GameMode == "Pxy")
            {
                float x = (PointOfPlayer.x - PointOfMouseOnGame.x) / 2;
                float y = (PointOfPlayer.y - PointOfMouseOnGame.y) / 2;
                PlayerPosition = new Vector3(x / 100, y / 100);
            }

            if (CentrifugalForce == true)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Input.mousePosition.y / 100, transform.position.x * -2, transform.position.x * -2.5f) ;
            }




            //----- Final Procress -----//

            transform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPosition.x,
                                             PlayerPosition.y,
                                             PlayerPosition.z);

            //----- Final Procress -----//////////
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my poor organization...

*In fact, I've tried doing smooth mouse movements on `Scratch` and it worked. So I tried to do it on Unity but it moved normally. or is it ineffective*

*Maybe it's because Scratch's framerate is only 32 frames...*

[Example Code image from Scratch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvx9W.png)

***thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Quaternion.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) is a great way of interpolating between rotations. It gets a point between `a` and `b` by `t`.

t is basically where inbetween the rotations it should output. We can use Time.deltaTime, so it gets slightly ahead of a, to b every frame. a will change to the current rotation, so it doesn't return the same point every time. You can add a speed, so it smooths it auicker or slower.

Here is an example code:

```
public float smoothSpeed = 1f;

...

if (CentrifugalForce == true)
    {
         Quaternion a = transform.localRotation;
         Quaternion b = Quaternion.Euler(Input.mousePosition.y / 100, transform.position.x * -2, transform.position.x * -2.5f);
         float t = Time.deltaTime * smoothSpeed;
         Quaternion smooth = Quaternion.Slerp(a, b, t);
         transform.localRotation = smooth;
    }
```

Let me know in coments if there are any problems! :)

Comment: i have a problems >>>(Cannot implicitly convert type '(float, float, float)' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion') (cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'float')

Comment: @TonmaiAttapon oops, I changed it.

Comment: Whoa, it works Thank, but I really need is a smooth movement position

Comment: @TonmaiAttapon oh, so not rotation? If you want to do this with Vector3s, you can use the exact same code, just replace b with target position, and a with transform.position. smooth should then be a vector3 equal to vector3.lerp(a, b, t)

Comment: It finally succeeded, thank you very much